# Android build fails with error - Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm, node-modules

While running the react-native android app using android studio I am getting this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried cleaning up the android project in android studio and also tried commands like:

```
gradlew --stop
```

to stop the already running daemons but nothing worked.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36660

or 

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35583

since I used to receive the same error while attempting to create a bundle for release, this method aids in problem solving. I hope that this will work for you 

dont go with this part ./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
or use this for aab ./gradlew bundleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAsset
This will cause your framework to collapse.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the follwoing.

```bash
./gradlew app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets  --stacktrace
```

Then, your issue will be shown more clearly.

In my case, the missing plugin in babel.config was that.